# Putting an option for a coupon code into a paypal button

Tags: button, paypal, payment, coupon

I was told by PayPal that currently the only way to add the option of entering a coupon code to a PayPal cart is to add code to the advanced variables section of the PayPal payment button. Can anyone share with me information on the code I would need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice how to guide that implements the coupon on top the button HTML code.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Y6EcOM_F10